# How can I be notified by email when an Amazon package is delivered?

Tags: notifications, amazon

Is there any way to have Amazon notify me by email every time a package is delivered?

Notifying via text messaging is not a good alternative since I use Google Voice and I [can't specify the correct carrier](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/which-carrier-should-i-use-for-google-voice).

Answer (score 1):

You can have UPS email you whenever they deliver a package, and I think Amazon uses them a lot. I do this, and the email usually comes 1-2 hours after the delivery.